# What is the sort of map[f]

Tags: z3, smt

Suppose I have a Sort T and I declare an array indexed by T, what is the sort of mapping over it?

e.g

```
(declare-datatypes ()
  ((T ....))) ; some index, may be finite or infinite (as in Int)
(declare-const a (Array T Int))
(declare-const b (Array Int Int))
(define-fun foo ((x Int)) Int)
(define-fun bar ((y Int)) Bool)
```

What is the sort of mapping foo on a? And the sort of mapping foo on b? Is there any way to mess up with the indexes type and obtain from an array indexed by T an array indexed by another sort, say e.g. Int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual sort-matching rules apply. That is, to `map` a function `f : A -> B` on an array, the array must have its range type `A`, and it'll turn it into a `B`, preserving the type of its domain.

Regarding your example: Regardless of what your `T` is, you'll simply have `Array T Int` as the final sort if you map `foo`, and `Array T Bool` as the result if you map `bar`. The following script type-checks without any issues:

```
(declare-datatypes ((T 0)) ((i Int)))
(declare-const a (Array T Int))
(declare-const b (Array Int Int))
(declare-fun foo (Int) Int)
(declare-fun bar (Int) Bool)

(define-fun e1 () (Array T  Int)   ((_ map foo) a))
(define-fun e2 () (Array T  Bool)  ((_ map bar) a))
(define-fun e3 () (Array Int Int)  ((_ map foo) b))
(define-fun e4 () (Array Int Bool) ((_ map bar) b))
```

Note that you *cannot* change the type of the domain (which is what you mean by `index` I presume) by mapping a function over an array. It only changes the range type.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought but could not find it anywhere in the specs, thank you for your time